# Как праивльно создать структуру бд

Tags: sql, postgresql

Есть таблица с умениями и оценка.
Тоесть , я не знаю сколько у него умений,он может перечислять их много. В конце я проставлю оценку.
Как создать таблицу, что-бы я по запросу мог получить все навыки этого человека.
Хранить все в виде строки или в файле json,есть другие варианты?

Comment: Список людей - отдельная таблица, список умений - отдельная таблица(т.к. у разных людей они могут повторятся), оценки - третья таблица(т.к. у разных людей они могут повторятся). И одна таблица, которая связывает предидущие три(то есть в ней по-факту три поля - ссылки на другие таблицы)

Comment: @Chubatiy  а в кратце : как делают ссылку на другую таблицу ?

Comment: @МаксимЛенский Перефразирую - четвертая таблица хранит в трех полях три ID. По одному на каждую из трех предидущих таблиц)

Comment: Если для одного умения одного человека ставится только одна оценка, то отдельная таблица оценок не нужна, оценка будет храниться непосредственно в таблице связей.

Comment: @Akina согласен. Вопрос как нужно по ТЗ. Но так или иначе - думаю вопрос решен)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Создай таблицу "Люди" с ид_человка и другими полями.
Создай таблицу "Навыки" с ид_навыка и другими полями.
Создай таблицу "Навыки людей" где будет всего три колонки: 
ид_человка,  ид_навыка и оценка_навыка. 
Так ты сможешь реализовать связь многие ко многим.